# Rewrite old URLs using htaccess and regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am having an issue on a WordPress-based website I run regarding a Rewrite Rule in my .htaccess file.

Recently overhauled the website and my permalink structure has changed. Previously, it was

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
```

Now, it is

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

The issue I'm running into is Google having all the .html links stored. So, visitors who follow the links via Google get a 404.

What I would like to happen is that anytime an incoming URL has the .html on the end and matches the permalink structure format, redirect to the same URL, just without the html extension.

I tried adding a Rewrite Rule to my .htaccess file and am having issues with it not working. I'm not sure what that issue is.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywebsite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}+)/([0-9]{2}+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ $1/$2/$3/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close but your regex is little bit off track. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywebsite.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.+?)\.html$ $1/$2/$3/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've implemented your version and it is still not working. The problem remains that the page just loads blank with the html extension. Not sure if this is caused by wordpress or not.

Comment: I figured it out. I had my rewrite rule after the standard RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] that wordpress places in. Thus, my rewrite wasn't being processed. Moved it above and boom.. it works. Thank you for your correcting of my rule!

Comment: Yes WP rules need to be after this otherwise that rule grabs all the requests. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Yes, the "new" WP form itself is going to have to be translated (rewritten) in .htaccess to a form that the server and PHP can understand (/index.php?year=yyyy&month=mm&... etc.). That would have to happen _after_ your conversion from the "old" WP format to the "new". Therefore, your conversion/rewrite has to happen _before_ anything else. By the way, it would also be possible to rewrite your "old" format directly into the final WP "real" format, if you fully understand what it is.